# How can I find sql server port number from windows registry?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, registry

How can I find sql server port number from windows? Is there any generic way to find port number for sql server 2000, 2005 and 2008?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**SQL Server 2000**

*Default instance*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP
```

*Named instance*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\(InstanceName)\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP
```

**SQL Server 2005**

There is no distinction between default and named instances. An instance is assigned a number based on the order it was installed. We first need to locate the registry key for the instance, which looks like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.#
```

'#' is the number assigned to the instance. The instance name is stored as the default value for this registry key. For a default instance, it is MSSQLSERVER.

Once the registry key for the instance is found, we know the TCP/IP registry key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.#\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\IPAll
```

**SQL Server 2008**

*Default instance*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\IPAll
```

*Named instance*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.(InstanceName)\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\IPAll
```

More information [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3764516/Discover-SQL-Server-TCP-Port.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You can also find the port in the SQL Server Configuration Manager:

- Select **Protocols for SQL2008** under **SQL server Network Configuration**
- Right click "TCP/IP" -> select **Properties**
- Select the **IP Addresses**-tab
- In the section **IP ALL**, you should see the ports

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure correct or not, u can use the Server Network Utility from the server and click Properties in TCP/IP for Enabled protocols list.

or can also check the port number an instance of SQL Server in the error log i.e. 10.0.0.1: 3306, the last 4 digit no after colon is the SQL server listening for the ip add