# Update WMI Instance Properties

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to update the TcpPort to "1433" and TcpDynamicPorts to "" using C# but none of the changes I make are taking affect. I can find the Instances in C# that I want to update and then confirm the properties exist in the instance but any update method gets ignored without error.

```
try
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10",
        "select * from ServerNetworkProtocolProperty where InstanceName='SQLEXPRESS' and ProtocolName='Tcp' and IPAddressName='IPAll'");
    foreach (ManagementObject instance in searcher.Get())
    {
        PutOptions options = new PutOptions();
        options.Type = PutType.UpdateOnly;

        foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Name == "PropertyName" && (string)property.Value == "TcpPort")
            {
                instance.SetPropertyValue("PropertyStrVal", "1433");
            }

            if (property.Name == "PropertyName" && (string)property.Value == "TcpDynamicPorts")
            {
                instance.SetPropertyValue("PropertyStrVal", "");
            }
        }
        instance.Put(options);
    }
}
catch (ManagementException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred setting the WMI data: " + e.Message);
}
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong? When I query the properties via WMI Explorer 2.0 everything has stayed the same.

Comment: You could try changing port number be writing/updating registry info instead of WMI. see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243250/how-can-i-find-sql-server-port-number-from-windows-registry) for registry location and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on who to write registry. Comparing your code to this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560467.aspx) i can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it's much more light-weight to update the registry than try and use WMI. I've managed to do everything I needed through registry changes. CHeers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier in my comment I think **writing into the registry** is way more **faster** and easier than accessing WMI for this task. So all you have to do is

```
private static void registryChangeSqlServerPort()
{
    /// SQL Server 2012 registry values
    ///      default instance
    ///          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\IPAll
    ///
    ///      named instance
    ///          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.(InstanceName)\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\TCP\IPAll

    string instanceName = "SQLEXPRESS";
    string key =
                string.Format("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.{0}\\MSSQLServer\\SuperSocketNetLib\\Tcp\\IPAll",
                            instanceName);
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);

    /// change TcpPort settings 
    string valueName = "TcpPort";
    string value = "1433";            
    regKey.SetValue(valueName, value, RegistryValueKind.String);

    /// change TcpDynamicPort settings 
    valueName = "TcpDynamicPorts";
    value = "";
    regKey.SetValue(valueName, value, RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

see this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243250/how-can-i-find-sql-server-port-number-from-windows-registry%20for%20other%20versions) for further keys on sql server.

Be aware that any **changes in the registry won't show up until restart of your machine** as it is only loaded once on startup. Even refreshing using F5 when watching regedit.exe did not work for me to show changed values!